# Replace empty lines in cells of pandas dataframes with space

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

API data fetched into a data frame contains blank values in few comments cells. I would eventually want to load the data frames to a csv file. When i load the data frame to csv, the blank lines within a comment are being treated as a new line, thereby giving wrong number of rows in csv.

Dataframe:

```
Employee_id | Employeee_comments
---------------------------------------
1           | 1. This is test comment 1
            | 2. This is test comment 2
            |
            | Comments above employee above
---------------------------------------------
2           | 1. This is test comment 3
```

I tried replacing using regex on the dataframe, but it replaced spaces between words.

`df = df.replace('\s+', '',regex=True)`

Please advise how i can replace just the blank lines with space for my output to look like below -

```
Employee_id | Employee_comments
--------------------------------
1           | 1. This is test comment 1 2. This is test comment 2 Comments above employee above
2           | 1. This is test comment 3
```

Comment: Do you mind to share a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `\n+` instead of `\s+` and replace the empty string by a space:

```
df = df.replace(r'\n+', ' ', regex=True)
```

`\n` only replaces new lines. `\s` replaces new lines, spaces, and tabs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used this and it worked :) ```df = df.replace('[\n\r\t]', ' ',regex=True)```